# The 'Microsoft SQL Server Subscriber Always Wins Conflict Resolver' failed to resolve the conflict

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, merge, merge-replication

I'm using merge replication to keep publisher database and subscriber database in sync. I changed the conflict resolver to 'Subscriber always wins'. Now, to test this, I force a conflict by changing a value of the same row both on server and client. Instead of the subscriber winning, I just get the following message:

```
 The 'Microsoft SQL Server Subscriber Always Wins Conflict Resolver' failed to resolve the conflict.
```

And that's it. I cannot find ONE other piece of info that will help me determine why the subscriber didn't win or anyone at that. Does anyone know how to use some of merges stored procedures or does anyone know why I would get this error without being able to find any additional info as to why this is happening.

**Also, this works for my colleague fine. But three other developers get this error**

Update: I did try to reinitialize and even delete my subscription with no luck. Could Management studio be holding on to something that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to install the MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 update. What a easy but dumb solution! :P

I'm still curious as to what was in that update that fixed it. I can't find much in the update specs.